# neo4j return a relationship that isn't defined

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am quite new to graph databases so what I am asking may be completely made up in my head.

I have three nodes, product, supplier and country which looks like the below (feedback welcome on appraoch).
[image: neo4j graph]

I would like to return the product and the country BUT I would like to return a relationship between them to show they are connected (I am envisioning two nodes connected by a line). I got this far where I can return product and supplier but no matter which way I spin the syntax I can't seem to get product and country connected by a relationship on return. Is that even possible?

`match (p1:part)<--(s1:supplier)-->(c1:country) return (p1)--(s1)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the APOC [virtual nodes and relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/virtual/virtual-nodes-rels/#virtual-nodes-rels) functions to visualize relationships (or nodes) that do not really exist in the DB.

For example:

```
MATCH (p:part)<-[:SUPPLIES]-(:supplier)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(c:country)
RETURN p, c, apoc.create.vRelationship(p, 'IS_IN', {}, c) as rel
```

produces this visualization in the neo4j Browser:

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you for that. It was exactly what I needed!