# Neo4J apoc.create.vRelationship unique relationsip

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

A few months back I asked [neo4j return a relationship that isn't defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60845782/neo4j-return-a-relationship-that-isnt-defined) and the answer was perfect.

```
MATCH (p:part)<-[:SUPPLIES]-(:supplier)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(c:country)
RETURN p, c, apoc.create.vRelationship(p, 'IS_IN', {}, c) as rel
```

The problem I am having with the above solution is I now have two nodes with lots of the exact same relationship type between them. Is there a way to return a distinct relationship based on it's type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WITH DISTINCT p, c` to filter out duplicate `p` and `c` pairs, so that there will only be a single virtual relationship between each pair:

```
MATCH (p:part)<-[:SUPPLIES]-(:supplier)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(c:country)
WITH DISTINCT p, c
RETURN p, c, apoc.create.vRelationship(p, 'IS_IN', {}, c) as rel
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Worked a treat, very much appreciated.